# My table generation goes bad

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets

recently i created a table to display all the information inside my database but it wont go so well.

here is my code

reveneuPage.jsp

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <th> Date </th>
                        <c:forEach var="revcodes" items="${revcodeList}">
                        <th>${revcodes.revcode}</th>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <!--<th> Total </th>-->
                        </thead>

                          <c:forEach var="revcodedate" items="${revcodeList}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${revcodedate.date}</td>
                            <c:forEach var="revcodeAmount" items="${revcodeList}">
                                <td>${revcodeAmount.amount}</td>
                            </c:forEach>



                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
```

revenuereport.java

```
String year = request.getParameter("year");
            String month = request.getParameter("month");
            a = new Db();
            String query = "SELECT\n" +
                            "  user_payment.revcode,\n" +
                            "  user_payment.date,\n" +
                            "  user_payment.amount,\n" +
                            "   revcode.revcodeactual\n" +
                            "FROM\n" +
                            "  user_payment, revcode\n" +
                            "WHERE\n" +
                            "  YEAR(user_payment.date) = '"+year+"' AND MONTH(user_payment.date) = '"+month+"' \n" +
                            "   and user_payment.revcode = revcode.revcodeactual\n" +
                            "Group By \n" +
                            "  user_payment.revcode, date\n" +
                            "Order By\n" +
                            "  user_payment.date ASC";

            resultSet = a.sqlQuery(query);
            while(resultSet.next()){
                revcodeList.add(new revcodes(
                        resultSet.getInt("revcodeactual"),
                        resultSet.getDate("date"),
                        resultSet.getDouble("amount")
                        ));

            }

            request.setAttribute("revcodeList", revcodeList);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("revenuePage.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

and after i execute this code, i got the iteration of 25 rows of the same date n revcodes..
what should i do? is my query wrongly structured? or i misused the object passing in servlet response and request?

i upload my screenshot [image: here]

Comment: try executing the query in database console, and see the result

Comment: Side note: for security reasons you should use prepared statements...

Comment: @Subin, i already run in mysql workbench, the output is great. but in table, because i want that particular date, it iterates and give me 25 row of the same value.

Comment: @home, im using prepared statement in my model. for security reason, i avoid direct link to my database.

Comment: @Keluang Yang Ko Kenal: but you build your query dynamically, so the prepared statement won't help: '"+year+"'